# Gridview paging and sorting do not work after changing datasource in codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sorting, paging

- I am having a gridview with an object datasource binded in the markup(aspx page).
  When page loads it directly works fine with all sorting and paging properties.
- However, i need to filter display on gridview so i have to change the datasource of the gridview on the code behind.
- It works fine.. i mean the filtering and displaying is good but paging and sorting doesnt work. Did you have a problem something like this?

Comment: i have just solved the issue. 
I was changing the datasource of the gridview which made me ask this question.
When i change the datasourceID of the gridview instead of datasource it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

dont change the gridviews datasource, check the object datasources properties instead, you can change its select query programatically.